# How to get list of files with checkin details from perforce through Java

Tags: java, perforce

My target is to provide a function with a branch name (or path) and in return reply back with a details like -

- What files got changed in this branch.
- Whats the revision version.
- Who made the changes.
- At what time.

I am aware of p4 describe but not sure, if I can use that or how using p4 api for Java.

Appreciate if you can suggest me relevant methods to look into so that I can investigate further in them.

Answer (score 0):

One useful way to approach this is:

```
p4 changes //depot/path/to/branch/...
```

This will give you a list of the changes, who made them, and when.

To find the files for each change, as you already have seen,

```
p4 describe -s change#
```

So issue the changes command first, to get the list of changes, then for each change, describe it.